# Importing many instances using MEF

Tags: c#, mef

I'm exporting some classes implementing the IFoo interface like this

```
public interface IFoo { }

[Export("A", typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo1 : IFoo { }

[Export("B", typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo2 : IFoo { }
```

When I try to import one of them using

```
 containter.GetExportedValue<IFoo>("A");
```

it works well but when I try to import all of them like this

```
[ImportMany]
IFoo[] foos;
```

it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Question - should foos not be a property with a get; set; ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have it both ways, declare 2 exports:

```
public interface IFoo { }

[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[Export("A", typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo1 : IFoo { }

[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[Export("B", typeof(IFoo))]
public class Foo2 : IFoo { }
```

Then it should work (i did a test sample and got it to work).

HTH,

Bab.

Comment: Hi @Baboon, I thought that using the [Export(string, Type)] does both export at the same time.

Comment: This works beautifully. Also, if you omit the name on one of the exports, this becomes the default, which is really useful to sidestep certain types of circular dependencies.

Comment: is there a way i can do [ImportMany] and still get the contract names?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the contract names on your exports.

```
[Export("A", typeof(IFoo))]
```

To

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
```

In the first scenario you are exporting a contract that matches the name "A" and the type IFoo, while in your import many you are importing everything that matches a contract of type IFoo (no contract name), so the exports with contract names aren't considered.

As baboon mentioned, you can have it both ways. You should consider if you need both in your application, if it is not the case, I would stick with only one way to keep things as simple as possible, otherwise I suggest using his approach.

Comment: Yes, but then he can't import just "A" anymore.

Comment: @Baboon: I wonder if it would be possible in this case to Export the part with and without the contract to make use of both type of imports. But I don't know if it's really necessary in this case.

Comment: Hi @Gilles, Baboon is right I need to use both way to import them.